# Goes to cinema / goes to the cinema

Tags: articles, definite-article, exam-questions

> Jason goes to cinema every Friday.

Or

> Jason goes to the cinema every Friday .

Which sentence is correct ? *The* is used with specific or particular noun but here it doesn't look like it's a specific subject , the sentence is conveying here that it's Jason's every Friday routine to go to cinema  . It can be any cinema.
It was asked in my exam and the solution has *to the cinema* as answer but I think its an error. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The cinema" is correct.

Whenever a noun is used in English in the singular, unless it is a proper name like "Bob" or "Russia", it must have either an article (a/the), a possessive (my/Sally's/etc), or one of a few other special adjectives, such as "one".

You could say, "Jason goes to a cinema every Friday." That would clearly indicate that it is not some specific cinema. But in practice, we usually say "Jason goes to the cinema every Friday." We use the definite article when speaking of something in the abstract, when we are talking about an undetermined member of a class. "Jason goes to the cinema every Friday." "Always look both ways before crossing the street." "The cat is a curious animal." Etc. Logically, by textbook explanations of "a" and "the", it sounds like you should use "a" because we are not talking about one specific instance but any instance. But in practice we use "the".

I think someone made up this rule to make it harder for foreigners to learn English. :-)

Comment: RE: _Whenever a noun is used in English in the singular..._ There are a few other notable exceptions besides _Bob_ and _Russia_, such as _school, work,_ and (in BrE) _hospital_.

Comment: @jr I should have said, "a COUNTABLE noun". Yes, non-countable nouns do not require an article.